# Other uses of the __name__ attribute

Tags: python

I'm learning Python by reading [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/index.html) online, and in Chapter 2 I see that you can use the `__name__` attribute for testing purposes, so I was wondering, does anyone knows about other uses for this attribute? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I once had a decorator for a command-line script file.

The decorator was used like this:

```
@command
def someFunc():
    # code goes here
```

The decorator was doing something like this:

```
commands = {}
def command(func)
    commands[func.__name__] = func
    return func
```

And then I could do something like this:

```
commandName = raw_input()
commands[commandName]();
```

Which would read a command's name from the console and call it - if it was labeled with the decorator before (so no dangerous calls would be possible as with `input`).

(In my code the name was taken from the command-line args, not `raw_input`.)

This easily let me provide commands accessible via their name. That's one of the uses - a general rule would be **"it's useful when you want to add your own semantics to the notion of function definition"**. The same goes for decorators in general.

*(BTW, there's `func.func_name` field, which is more correct to use than `func.__name__` because identifiers starting with `__` are supposed to be private in Python, AFAIK - just a minor detail)*

Comment: Great, I still need to fully understand what you said, thanks for the func.func_name tip.

Comment: Note that that's `__name__` on a function; the `__name__` you found first was on a module, indicating its name as imported, or `'__main__'` for the initial called module; in any case, `sys.modules[__name__]` is the current module.

Answer (score 1):

It can be very useful when debugging. When writing frameworks (or any other highly generic piece of software), you can easily debug using **name** to know what's being passed around.